# Does Linux has a fundamental limitation about using multiple cd/dvd drives simultaneously?

Tags: iso, dvd, scsi, burning

I have two cd/dvd drives in my laptop. One is an external USB drive and the other is the SATA drive that came with it.

And I can't burn two DVDs at the same time in both of them at full speed no matter what I do.

First I tried running Wodim in two separate instances, reading the same file. Note the file is in a SSD, which can be read in speeds as great as 50 Mb/s easily.

But that caused both dvd's to burn at an average speed of 1.5x while suffering constant buffer underruns.

Then I copied the file to a separate media (an external HDD) and tried again to use two Wodim instances, but each one reading from a separate media. Didn't work.

Then I tried downloading AnyBurn for windows and running it with wine. Anyburn can burn to multiple drives simultaneously. It worked, but again too slow, at speeds like 2x.

Then by last I tested running AnyBurn in one drive and wodim in the other - Each one reading the files from different media. This time Wodim got to burn at 8x (top speed) and had no buffer underrun. But Anyburn was very slow and got an error mid-burn.

Also, note both AnyBurn and Wodim work perfectly when running alone and burning to a single drive, with any of the 2 drives.

The problem always comes when I try to burn in two drives at the same time.

What is happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: You never got an answer to this here in this forum but did you ever figure this out? I just purchased a new DVD reader in hopes that I could backup more than one disc at the same time, but I'm finding that when one is reading, the other one won't backup anything. In fact, I can't even use tools to read from it.